# Create list with first and last day of month for given period

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-range, generate-series

I have to generate a list with two columns of day intervals for every month in a specific period. First column must be the first day of month and the second column the last day of month.

Example:
Start date: `2014-01-01`
End date: `2014-06-30`

The result should be in two columns:

```
1. 2014-01-01 | 2014-01-31
2. 2014-02-01 | 2014-02-28
3. 2014-03-01 | 2014-03-31
4. 2014-04-01 | 2014-04-30
5. 2014-05-01 | 2014-05-31
6. 2014-06-01 | 2014-06-30
```

I have two functions that get the first and last day from a date.
I am trying to combine two series but with no luck.

```
select i::date
from generate_series(first_day('2014-01-01')
                    ,first_day('2014-06-30'), '1 month'::interval) i

select i::date
from generate_series(last_day('2014-01-01')
                    ,last_day('2014-06-30'), '1 month'::interval) i
```

The second function does not show the last day correctly when it is in the series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20089063/1216680):

```
select d::date as start_date,(d + '1 month'::interval - '1 day'::interval )::date end_date
from generate_series('2014-01-01'::date, '2014-06-30'::date, '1 month'::interval) d
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a month and subtract a day - in a *single* interval expression:

```
SELECT d AS mon_first
     , d + interval '1 month - 1 day' AS mon_last
FROM   generate_series(timestamp '2014-01-01'
                     , timestamp '2014-06-30'
                     , interval  '1 month') d;
```

- [The manual about `interval` input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT)

Further reading ("end of day" is very similar to "last day of month"):

- [How to get the end of a day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689384/how-to-get-the-end-of-a-day/27728482#27728482)

About generating a time series:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)