# How to get the end of a day?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4. I have a table column with timestamps (`timestamp without timezone`). For instance:

```
       date
-------------------
2014-05-27 12:03:20
2014-10-30 01:20:03
2013-10-19 16:34:34
2013-07-10 15:24:26
2013-06-24 18:15:06
2012-07-14 07:09:14
2012-05-13 04:46:18
2013-01-04 21:31:10
2013-03-26 10:17:02
```

How to write an SQL query which returns all timestamps in the format:

```
xxxx-xx-xx 23:59:59
```

Every timestamp will be set to the end of the day.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Take the date, truncate it, add one day and subtract one second:

```
select date_trunc('day', date) + interval '1 day' - interval '1 second'
```

You can put the logic in an `update` if you want to change the data in the table.

Of course, you can also add 24*60*60 - 1 seconds:

```
select date_trunc('day', date) + (24*60*60 - 1) * interval '1 second'
```

But that seems less elegant.

Comment: Just to add that if you want precision to the millisecond you can replace the 'second' part with 'millisecond', ending up with 'xxxx-xx-xx 23:59:59.999'.

Comment: I like `select the_date::date + interval '1 day - 1 second';` Also, don't name your columns after reserved words.

Answer (score 33):

**Many ways.**

We are talking about the type `timestamp`. The preferred type in Postgres is `timestamptz`. Be aware of the difference! See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Using the column name **`ts`** in my examples. "date" for a timestamp column would be misleading.

#### Last second of the same day

1. Cast to `date`, add `integer '1'`, then subtracting `interval '1 second'`.

   ```sql
   ts::date + 1 - interval '1 sec'
   ```

   The addition date + int is the only case that actually requires the type `date`. All other expressions in this answer work with `date_trunc()` just as well - or even ever so slightly faster.
2. Postgres [interval input](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT) allows a single expression with multiple time units. No need for two operations.

   ```sql
   ts::date              + interval '1 day - 1 sec'
   date_trunc('day', ts) + interval '1 day - 1 sec'
   ```
3. Simpler yet, add the desired time component to the date (or start of the day):

   ```sql
   date_trunc('day', ts) + interval '23:59:59'
   ```
4. Same thing with type `time`:

   ```sql
   date_trunc('day', ts) + time '23:59:59'
   ```

#### Last timestamp of the same day

`xxxx-xx-xx 23:59:59` is **not** the "end of the day". The Postgres [`timestamp` data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) (currently, and not likely to change) stores values with microsecond resolution. The latest possible timestamp for a day is **`xxxx-xx-xx 23:59:59.999999`**.

5. ```sql
   date_trunc('day', ts) + interval '1 day - 1 microsecond'
   ```
6. ```sql
   date_trunc('day', ts) + interval '23:59:59.999999'
   ```
7. ```sql
   date_trunc('day', ts) + time '23:59:59.999999'
   ```

This last expression should be **[fastest](https://dbfiddle.uk/mSttpO6b) besides being correct**.

#### Start of the next day

Typically, operating with the start of the next day as **exclusive upper bound** is the superior approach. Does not depend on implementation details and is even simpler to generate.

8. ```sql
   ts::date + 1  -- returns date!
   ```
9. ```sql
   date_trunc('day', ts) + interval '1 day'  -- returns timestamp
   ```

All work in any version since at least Postgres 8.4. Demo in Postgres 16:

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2wYdkSyT)