# SQL SELECT that excludes rows with any of a list of values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, where-in

I have found many Questions and Answers about a SELECT excluding rows with a value "NOT IN" a sub-query (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231712/sql-not-in-not-working)). But how to **exclude a list of values** rather than a sub-query?

I want to search for rows whose timestamp is within a range but exclude some specific date-times. In English, that would be:

> Select all the ORDER rows recorded between noon and 2 PM  today except for the ones of these times: Today 12:34, Today 12:55, and Today 13:05.

SQL might be something like:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM order_
WHERE recorded_ >= ?
AND recorded_ < ?
AND recorded_ NOT IN ( list of date-times… )
;
```

So two parts to this Question:

- How to write the SQL to exclude rows having any of a list of values?
- How to set an arbitrary number of arguments to a `PreparedStatement` in JDBC?
  (the arbitrary number being the count of the list of values to be excluded)

Comment: your SQL will work to exclude values as described. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives answers the NOT IN list.

Comment: You want `recorded_ <> ALL( ? )`, with a param of type `timestamp[]`. Not sure how to feed this in via JDBC, though.

Comment: @NickBarnes: `NOT IN` is effectively the same as `<> ALL()`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31192557/939860. The problem with both: they fail if NULL is involved on either side of the expression. The expression evaluates to NULL; but only TRUE passes a `WHERE` condition: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19528722/939860

Comment: As explained in the comments, `NOT IN (...)` is equivalent to `<> ALL (ARRAY[...])`.

You can create an array in JDBC with `createArrayOf`, then pass that as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

#### Pass *array*

A fast and NULL-safe alternative would be a `LEFT JOIN` to an unnested array:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM   order_ o
LEFT  JOIN unnest(?::timestamp[]) x(recorded_) USING (recorded_)
WHERE  o.recorded_ >= ?
AND    o.recorded_ <  ?
AND   x.recorded_ IS NULL;
```

This way you can prepare a single statement and pass **any number of timestamps** as array.

The explicit cast `::timestamp[]` is only necessary if you cannot type your parameters (like you can in [prepared statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-prepare.html)). The array is passed as single `text` (or `timestamp[]`) literal:

```
'{2015-07-09 12:34, 2015-07-09 12:55, 2015-07-09 13:05}', ...
```

Or put `CURRENT_DATE` into the query and pass times to add like [outlined by @drake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31306776/939860) . More about adding a `time` / `interval` to a `date`:

- [How to get the end of a day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689384/how-to-get-the-end-of-a-day/27728482#27728482)

#### Pass *individual values*

You could also use a `VALUES` expression - or any other method to create an ad-hoc table of values.

```
SELECT o.*
FROM   order_ o
LEFT  JOIN (VALUES (?::timestamp), (?), (?) ) x(recorded_)
                                         USING (recorded_)
WHERE  o.recorded_ >= ?
AND    o.recorded_ <  ?
AND    x.recorded_ IS NULL;
```

And pass:

```
'2015-07-09 12:34', '2015-07-09 12:55', '2015-07-09 13:05', ...
```

This way you can only pass a **predetermined number of timestamps**.

#### Asides

For up to 100 parameters (or your setting of [`max_function_args`](http://machttp://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-preset.html#GUC-MAX-FUNCTION-ARGS)), you could use a server-side function with a `VARIADIC` parameter:

- [Return rows matching elements of input array in plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978310/select-rows-such-that-names-match-elements-of-input-array-for-pgsql-function/17978831#17978831)

I know that you are aware of `timestamp` characteristics, but for the general public: equality matches can be tricky for timestamps, since those can have up to 6 fractional digits for seconds and you need to match *exactly*.

#### Related

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)
- [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91539/3684)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM order_
WHERE recorded_ BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE + time '12:00' AND CURRENT_DATE + time '14:00')
      AND recorded_ NOT IN (CURRENT_DATE + time '12:34', 
                            CURRENT_DATE + time '12:55',
                            CURRENT_DATE + time '13:05')
 ;
```

Comment: I'm using Java and JDBC. Can I make the list in parens simply a list of java.sql.Timestamp instances? Like this: `NOT IN ( ? , ? , ? )`  with `preparedStatement.setTimestamp( 3 , timestampObject1 ); ", repeating for 4, 5 and so on?