# Get first & last date for next 12 months in sql in datetime format

Tags: sql, sql-server, calendar

I am trying to get first date & last date for next 12 months from the date the report/query is run.I was able to get next 12months by using below query but not with first and last dates. Any suggestions on how to do this are appreciated.

```
SELECT STR(MONTH(DATEADD(mm,Number,GETDATE())),2)+'/'
      + STR(YEAR(DATEADD(mm,Number,GETDATE())),4),DATEPART(MM,'january '+'01 1900')
   FROM Master.dbo.spt_values
  WHERE NAME IS NULL
    AND Number BETWEEN 0 AND 11
```

But results it gives are:

[image]

But what I expect:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create list with first and last day of month for given period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583877/create-list-with-first-and-last-day-of-month-for-given-period)

Comment: @TabAlleman .. the linked question is for Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `EOMONTH` function is supported, use

```
SELECT dateadd(day,1,dateadd(month,number-1,EOMONTH(getdate()))) as mth_start,
dateadd(month,number,EOMONTH(getdate())) as mth_end
FROM Master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE NAME IS NULL
AND Number BETWEEN 0 AND 11
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
   SELECT 
CONVERT(datetime,  STR(MONTH(DATEADD(mm,Number,GETDATE())),2)+'/01/'+ STR(YEAR(DATEADD(mm,Number,GETDATE())),4)) firstdate,
dateadd(day,-1,CONVERT(datetime, STR(MONTH(DATEADD(mm,Number+1,GETDATE())),2)+'/01/'+ STR(YEAR(DATEADD(mm,Number+1,GETDATE())),4))) lastdate
FROM Master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE NAME IS NULL
AND Number BETWEEN 0 AND 11
```

to fetch last date of month, we can remove one day from first date of next month.